# RobotFramework Locate elements with identical class

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

im currently working on a test automation with robotframework and the seleniumlibrary.
I ran into following problem:
I cant locate the right element, because there are two element with identical classes.
The elements are located on an popup window in our system.
The html of the two elements look like this:

First element:

```html
<mais-radio _ngcontent-jgg-c45="" _nghost-jgg-c46="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input _ngcontent-jgg-c46="" class="original-radiobutton ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" name="pflege_beduerftig" id="pflege_beduerftig0">
<div _ngcontent-jgg-c46="" class="mais-rb" tabindex="1">
</div></mais-radio>
```

Second element:

```html
<mais-radio _ngcontent-jgg-c45="" _nghost-jgg-c46="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input _ngcontent-jgg-c46="" class="original-radiobutton ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" name="pflege_beduerftig" id="pflege_beduerftig1">
<div _ngcontent-jgg-c46="" class="mais-rb" tabindex="1"></div>
</mais-radio>
```

There just the different id that can seperate those elements, but robotframework cant click the elements with the locator finding the id.

Is there any way i can locate just the second element other than using the xpath method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `ID = pflege_beduerftig1`  ? What error you are getting when you use this ID ?

Comment: If I use ID = pflege_beduerftig1 I get the error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: The two elements should have different parents somewhere up the tree; so construct your css locator starting off the unique parent for the element you want to target.

Comment: I´ve already tried that, but it didn´t work either.

Answer (score 0):

Element needs to be in view Port, try the code given below :

```
Execute JavaScript    window.document.evaluate("//input[contains(@id,'pflege_beduerftig1')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: I´ve tried it, but the error code is the same as before: 'ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)'

I also tried: 'Scroll Element Into View' but it didn´t help.

Comment: how do you interact with that element manually ? Do you have to perform mouse scrolling ?

Comment: No, the pop up is actually not scrollable, so I dont know why the element isn´t clickable.
The element is a clickable Radio button.
Is it possible, that the pop up is the problem?

Comment: if you can click manually then pop up should not be a problem

Comment: Yeah I know I thought the same, but the problem still remains unsolved.